# what is best possible way to communicate between dynamically loaded nested components in angular 2+

Tags: angular

I am working on project based on angular 2+.  In this project components are loading on basis of particular configuration. Here the problem is when I load components I am able to pass input but I not sure how to subscribe to events emitted by components. What could be the best possible way to communicate between components?

P.S. It is nested structure of dynamically loading components

Comment: use @Output() ..

Comment: you could observables